# functional programming in R

Tags: r, functional-programming

I have been reading the Functionals from [github](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Functionals). One suggestion in the page was to use `call_function` if  one is working with a list of functions. Here is the code from the page:

```
call_fun <- function(f, ...) f(...)
f <- list(sum, mean, median, sd)
lapply(f, call_fun, x = runif(1e3))
```

The output was posted as:

```
# [[1]]
# [1] 498
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 0.498
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 0.49
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 0.29
```

However, I was not able to replicate the above results. I got the error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[4L]], ...) : could not find function "f"
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have redefined the function `sd`:

```
sd = 2

call_fun <- function(f, ...) f(...)
f <- list(sum, mean, median, sd)
lapply(f, call_fun, x = runif(1e3))
#Error in FUN(X[[4L]], ...) : could not find function "f"
```

Restart your session or do `rm(sd)`.

Comment: Thanks @eddi. I am not sure whether my question will be useful for future users. I will be happy to delete if it seems trivial.

Comment: I'm not sure that you _can_ delete it. It already has an upvote (mine) and upvotes on the answer (mine and anothers). I'm still curious if there is a programmatic way to handle the problem. I tried `call_fun <- function(f, ...) match.fun(f)(...)` which succeeds in the simple case and fails in the same manner with `sd==5` in the environment.

Comment: @Metrics I've run into this exact same issue before with `sd` (there are only so many two letter variable names), so it's probably not too uncommon of a mistake (not so sure though one can find this question through a search engine)